# iOS SegmentedControl equivalent in Android

Tags: android, uisegmentedcontrol

What is a good Android analog of iOS's `UISegmentedControl`?

Answer (score 32):

I just wrote a similar implementation here: https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton

It overrides RadioGroup instead of RadioButton and doesn't override the onDraw method so XML styling still works.

Comment: For any one who don't want to have so many resource image files, you may define your RadioButton background like this [segmented_button_background_first.xml](http://code.google.com/p/android-batsg/source/browse/android-batsg-demo/res/drawable/segmented_button_background_first.xml) file (there is more sample [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-batsg/source/browse/android-batsg-demo/res/drawable)). I also rewrite makeramen's code for more flexible use like [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-batsg/wiki/SegmentedControl)

Comment: @umbalaconmeogia that looks awesome, feel free to submit as a pull request if you want!

Answer (score 12):

Benjamin Ferrari has a nice implementation here: http://blog.bookworm.at/2010/10/segmented-controls-in-android.html . Essentially he's just overridden the RadioButton.

Comment: He added a github project that contains a library that you can include in your project that has ICS styled controls that are really slick.  Here's the link [https://github.com/bookwormat/segcontrol](https://github.com/bookwormat/segcontrol)