# Segmented control in Android

Tags: android

I need to use IPhone like **segmented control** in Android. Is there a default control for the same? What might be the best and efficient way to do so?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952991/how-to-create-iphone-like-segmented-control-view-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Segment control in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538421/segment-control-in-android)

Comment: I'm dumbfounded that this was not a foundational element in Android development. Such a basic common element. And, AFAICT, still not available in 2023? Is that possible? Embarrassing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve segmented control functionality with [Radio Group](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)

Here are few examples [this](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-radiobutton-example) and [Hello Form](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html)

Comment: such an uninspired answer doesn't deserve to be the accepted answer! Btw. the links don't work anymore.

Answer (score 9):

What you are looking for is **MaterialButtonToggleGroup**, and you can put in some **Material Button**. It is pretty similar to iOS *UISegmentContorol*.

It looks like this:
[image]

source with example: https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons#toggle-button

Comment: an other example of its usage https://www.journaldev.com/31950/android-materialbuttontogglegroup

Comment: Is it possible to have a slide animation on it?

Answer (score 5):

I have achieved it using build in Views.

**MySegmentActivity**

```
public class SegmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Button> buttonList = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_segment_layout);

        mContext = SegmentActivity.this;
        initSegmentButtons();
    }

    private void initSegmentButtons() {

        buttonList = new ArrayList<>();

        Button dayBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_day);
        Button weekBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_week);
        Button monthBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_month);

        dayBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        weekBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        monthBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonList.add(dayBtn);
        buttonList.add(weekBtn);
        buttonList.add(monthBtn);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_day:
                buttonList.get(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_orange_selected);
                buttonList.get(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_orange);
                buttonList.get(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_orange);
                break;
            case R.id.btn_week:
                buttonList.get(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_orange);
                buttonList.get(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_orange_selected);
                buttonList.get(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_orange);
                break;
            case R.id.btn_month:
                buttonList.get(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_orange);
                buttonList.get(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_orange);
                buttonList.get(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_orange_selected);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**layout.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_day"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_orange"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Day"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_week"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_orange"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Week"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_month"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_orange_selected"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Month"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**btn_bg_orange.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/orange" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

**btn_bg_orange_selected**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/orange" />

    <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a modern iOS-styled SegmentedControl, you can consider using:
https://github.com/alanvan0502/segmented-control-group

Comment: This one is best. But my existing project is using Android Support Library. Where using your suggestion is forcing me to migrate to AndroidX. Which is big headache.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a SegmentCustomControl for Android.

**SegmentTestActivity.class**

```
public class SegmentTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context mContext;
    private SegmentView segmentView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.segment_test_activity);

        mContext = SegmentTestActivity.this;

        segmentView = (SegmentView) findViewById(R.id.segment_view);
        segmentView.setOnSegmentSelectedListener(new OnSegmentSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSegmentSelected(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Segment selected at Index : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**segment_test_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <custom.rnd.SegmentView
        android:id="@+id/segment_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:numberOfSegment="3"
        app:segmentColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:selectedTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:textSize="16sp"
        app:unSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <custom.rnd.SegmentView
        android:id="@+id/segment_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:numberOfSegment="2"
        app:segmentColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:selectedTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:titlesOfSegment="New,OLD"
        app:unSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**SegmentView**

```
public class SegmentView extends LinearLayout{

    public static final String TAG = "SegmentView";
    private OnSegmentSelectedListener onSegmentSelectedListener;
    private SegmentView segmentView;
    private int numberOfSegments = 0;
    private List<String> titlesOfSegment;
    private int selectedTextColor;
    private int unSelectedTextColor;
    private int segmentColorSelected;
    /*private int defaultSelectedColor = Color.parseColor("#c13d1f");
    private int defaultUnSelectedColor = Color.parseColor("#ea8d21");*/

    public SegmentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initLayout(context, attrs);
    }

    public SegmentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initLayout(context, attrs);
    }

    private void initLayout(Context mContext, AttributeSet attrs) {
        segmentView = this;

        titlesOfSegment = new ArrayList<>();

        TypedArray typedArray = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SegmentView);
        numberOfSegments = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.SegmentView_numberOfSegment, 0);
        String titleWithComma = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.SegmentView_titlesOfSegment);
        selectedTextColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentView_selectedTextColor, Color.WHITE);
        unSelectedTextColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentView_unSelectedTextColor, Color.parseColor("#c13d1f"));
        segmentColorSelected = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.SegmentView_segmentColor, 0);

        //orientation = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.SegmentView_orientation , 0);

        int unitsTextSize = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.SegmentView_textSize, 0);

        if (titleWithComma != null && !titleWithComma.isEmpty()) {
            String[] arrayOfTitles = titleWithComma.split(",");
            for (String x : arrayOfTitles) {
                titlesOfSegment.add(x);
            }
        }
        typedArray.recycle();

        segmentView.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

        /*if(orientation == 0){
            segmentView.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
        }
        else{
            segmentView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            segmentView.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        }*/

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSegments; i++) {

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

            /*if(orientation != 0)
                param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f);*/

            Button btn = new Button(mContext);

            if (titlesOfSegment != null && titlesOfSegment.size() == numberOfSegments)
                btn.setText(titlesOfSegment.get(i));
            else
                btn.setText("Segment " + i);
            btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            if(unitsTextSize != 0){
                btn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, unitsTextSize);
            }
            else
                btn.setTextSize(14.0f);

            if (i == 0) {
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_orange_selected);
                btn.setTextColor(selectedTextColor);
                updateBorderAndSolidColor(btn);

            } else {
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_orange);
                btn.setTextColor(unSelectedTextColor);

                if (segmentColorSelected != 0) {
                    //changeSolidColor(btn ,segmentColorUnSelected);
                    changeStrokeColor(btn, segmentColorSelected);
                }
            }

            final int x = i;
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (onSegmentSelectedListener != null)
                        onSegmentSelectedListener.onSegmentSelected(x);
                    handleClick(x, view);

                }
            });
            segmentView.addView(btn, param);
        }
    }

    private void updateBorderAndSolidColor(Button btn) {
        if (segmentColorSelected != 0) {
            changeStrokeColor(btn, segmentColorSelected);
        }
        if (segmentColorSelected != 0) {
            changeSolidColor(btn, segmentColorSelected);
        }
    }

    public void setOnSegmentSelectedListener(OnSegmentSelectedListener onSegmentSelectedListener) {
        this.onSegmentSelectedListener = onSegmentSelectedListener;
    }


    private void handleClick(int position, View view) {
        Button btnView = null;

        for (int iter = 0; iter < segmentView.getChildCount(); iter++) {
            btnView = (Button) segmentView.getChildAt(iter);
            if (iter == position) {
                btnView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_orange_selected);
                btnView.setTextColor(selectedTextColor);
                updateBorderAndSolidColor(btnView);
            } else {
                btnView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_orange);
                btnView.setTextColor(unSelectedTextColor);
                if (segmentColorSelected != 0)
                    changeStrokeColor(btnView, segmentColorSelected);
            }
        }
    }

    private void changeStrokeColor(Button view, int colorCode) {
        GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) view.getBackground();
        //update value 3 according to your need.
        drawable.setStroke(3, colorCode); // set stroke width and stroke color
    }

    private void changeSolidColor(Button view, int colorCode) {
        GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) view.getBackground();
        drawable.setColor(colorCode); // set solid color
    }
}
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="SegmentView">
        <attr name="numberOfSegment" format="integer" />
        <attr name="titlesOfSegment" format="string" />
        <attr name="selectedTextColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="unSelectedTextColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="segmentColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="textSize" format="dimension" />

        <!--<attr name="orientation">
            <enum name="horizontal" value="0" />
            <enum name="vertical" value="1" />
        </attr>-->
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

and Listener

```
public interface OnSegmentSelectedListener {
    void onSegmentSelected(int position);
}
```