# Segment control in android

Tags: android

Can any one please tell me how to make a segment control in android, exactly given below -

[image]

I am confused what images should I use . How to cut images and use them as resources to get exact same segment control like this. And which library would be perfect to achieve this ?

Comment: This is an other good alternative: https://github.com/hoang8f/android-segmented-control

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41361709/3496570

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are dozen of good articles on segment control implementation... but following are the good ones , that helped me.. **Intermediate Example** is closest to your requirement.

[Basic Example](http://github.com/nairteashop/SegmentedControl)

[Intermediate Example](http://ttlnews.blogspot.com/2011/09/segmented-button-control-in-android.html)

[Github Segment Control Example One](https://github.com/bookwormat/segcontrol)

[Github Segment Control Example Two](https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton)

[Github Ceryle SegmentedButton (the richest)](https://github.com/ceryle/SegmentedButton)

For creating Menus , u need to have some photoshop skills, although **this website can create navigation for u online** as well  [Create Navigation Online](http://www.cssmenubuilder.com/build-horizontal-menu)

Comment: Intermediate example was a bit helpful. Thanks

Comment: First link is broken.

Comment: Here's the basic example with a working link: https://github.com/nairteashop/SegmentedControl