# Segmented Control Equivalent in Android Development

Tags: android

I am new in Android development and I am wondering if this is appropriate to ask here.

What is the equivalent of iOS Segmented Control in Android?

### ***Perhaps something like these?***

[image]

Comment: In android Tab Layout  Ex: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

Comment: Could you please post as answer? and not comment? @Piyush

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: This works fine for me https://github.com/Kaopiz/android-segmented-control

Comment: I done it with Android View http://stackoverflow.com/a/41361709/3496570